# Webform limit to multiple choice question

Tags: 7, webforms

Anyone know of a way to take a multiple choice (checkbox) question on a Webform and only allow the person to select two or three options and all other options become disabled? Using WebForm module?
Version: 7.x-4.15

Comment: What version of the Webform module are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered a module called [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation), works fine. But the user will only know that he can't submit more than x answers after clicking the submit button.